# debug mode breakpoints does not work in valueChangeListener

Tags: java, ajax, maven, primefaces

ı do not get any warning or error messages in console. debug mode breakpoints does not work in valueChangeListener method in bean class. another methods work at debug mode in bean class. ı tried also ajax with listener.(ı am using maven) does anbody have idea?

xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="/template/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="menu">
        <ui:include src="/template/menu.xhtml">
            <ui:param name="menuId" value="4"></ui:param>
        </ui:include>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <ui:include src="../template/progress.xhtml"></ui:include>              
            <h:form id="nameForm">                  
                <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"   
   />
                <b:column col-xs="12" col-md="8">
                <b:panel style="width:80%">
                    <b:panelGrid colSpans="4,8">
                        <p:tabView id="tabView" style="min-width:450px;" >
                            <p:tab title="..." >
                                <b:panelGrid colSpans="3,9" columns="2" 
                               cellpadding="10">
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{beanController.a}" 
                                        id="AId"
                                        valueChangeListener="#{beanController.aSelected}" onchange="submit()">                                          
                                        <p:ajax event="change"/>
                                        <f:selectItems 
                                            value="#{beanController.aList}" /> 
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>                                  
                                </b:panelGrid>
                            </p:tab>
```

beanController.java:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "beanController")
@ViewScoped
public class BeanController {
public void aSelected(ValueChangeEvent event){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use <f:ajax />, like that :   

<f:ajax event="blur" listener="#{beanController.updateDataListener}" update=":#{p:component('tabView')}"/> 


@ManagedBean(name = "beanController")
@SessionScoped
public class BeanController implements Serializable{
   private String a;
   public void updateDataListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
    {
          ......
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Tran, ı tried your suggestion. ı have changed ajax in xhtml and also  changed implements and method in bean class but debug does not work in listener method.

Comment: Firstly you can try this showcase : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/listener.xhtml
Create a simple file like that to make sure your project support to run.
If you can, share your project here. I'll try to debug for you.